# Changing html element property via javascript does not change appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a html page, with a navigation bar. Ideally, once user select one option, that option background image would change. However, I was not able to achieve that, by using javascript to dynamically change the list property.

The html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="includes/css/content.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>
function select(id)
{
    alert(id);
    var list = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
        list[i].class='random';
    }
    document.getElementById(id).class='selected';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainContent">
            <div class = 'nav'>
                <ul>
                    <li class='selected' id='home' onClick="select(this.id)"><a href="#" ><span  style='color:gray'>Home</span></a></li>
                    <li id='system' onClick="select(this.id)"><a href="#" ><span  style='color:gray'>Systems</span></a></li>
                    <li id='temp' onClick="select(this.id)" ><a href="#"><span  style='color:gray'>Notification Template</span></a></li>

                </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css file looks like this:

```
.nav .selected a{
background-size:cover;
background: url(../images/nav.gif) no-repeat top;
color:white;
}
```

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `list[i].class='random';` should be `list[i].className += ' random';`

Comment: Did .className fix your problem, or is it still not cooperating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `class` does not exist for HTMLElement.  Use `className` to set the css class.

For a full list of properties - see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting a class that way, you'll want to use `.className` [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className ]